# Cards list having list inside each card in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

[image]
What is the best way to implement list of cards with autonomic list inside each card?
I want to make something looks like in the picture

Comment: Obviously you can't have a scroll list inside the card because the cards themselves are scrolling.  The card is just a list preview, so you just make three views in a column and show the first three items in the list.  In other words, the three lines are "hard-coded". The Show More link navigates to a complete list.

Comment: When i pressed on show more on the example it didn't navigated me anywhere just added more option on the same place .

Comment: And did it keep the other cards in place?  My version of the app looks different from yours.  Each line is its own card.  And when you click Show More, it shows the whole list for what you clicked and hides the others.

Comment: Yes the other cards haven't  disappeared